# Find and replace using regular expressions (regex) in visual studio?

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, replace, find

I am converting from VB.net to C#.Net.

I need to replace `Session("something")` or `Session("Others")` to `Session["something"]` or `Session["Others"]` in the whole project. What regex i need to use in the find box and what's in the replace box. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Make sure you check on the option `use the regular expression`.

- Find what: `Session\("{.*?}"\)`
- Replace with: `Session["\1"]`

Note: using lazy operator `?` here is try to stop when finding the first match. Thus, it should be able to handle cases like:

1. `Session("Types") = new SelectList(xxx, "Code", "Description");`
2. `((((Session("something)))))))))"))))`

---

**P.S.:** In VS2013, you should use the following instead:

- Find what: `Session\("(.*?)"\)`
- Replace with: `Session["$1"]`

Comment: Those two session names are examples. There are different sessions. I do not have any session named something. I am trying to replace all in one go. I can find sessions by ------ Session\("[a-zA-Z]+"\) -------- but do not know how to replace

Comment: @MJK Updated the answer. Check it out.

Comment: Thanks it works. The only problem is if there is another bracket")" in the line it is selecting to the end of the last closing bracket

Comment: @MJK Can you give such an example?

Comment: For example : Session("Types") = new SelectList(_Service.GetTypes(), "Code", "Description");

Comment: @MJK Fixed. There is another problem though, e.g. `Session("Types))))")` (have `)` in `""`). I will try to solve this and update this answer after working it out.